# Calculating quintiles

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to calculate the quintile range for a dataset (0 and 5) and have used this as as my basis of calculation (I've pasted the query below from the website)
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/PERCENT_RANK/141532/

```
WITH C AS
(
   SELECT
      SalesPersonID,
      SaleYear, SaleAmt,
      rk = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SaleAmt),
      nr = COUNT(*) OVER ()
   FROM ##Sales
)
SELECT
    SalesPersonID,
    SaleYear,
    SaleAmt,
    PercentileRank = 1.0*(rk-1)/(nr-1)
FROM C;
```

What would I need to modify to get this in a quintile range?

Comment: sample data and expected result please

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH C AS
(
   SELECT
      SalesPersonID,
      SaleYear, SaleAmt,
      rk = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SaleAmt),
      nr = COUNT(*) OVER ()
   FROM ##Sales
)
SELECT
    SalesPersonID,
    SaleYear,
    SaleAmt,
    PercentileRank = 1.0*(rk-1)/(nr-1),
    Quintile=(rk-1)/(nr/5)+1
FROM C;
```

Comment: I'll have a look at this. Thanks